# Spring Security: How to allow access to only login page using OAuth 2.0?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I have a Spring Boot project using Spring Security and OAuth2.0 libraries.
I confirmed when I accessed `http://localhost:8080/login`, the default login view is displayed and I could log in.

[image]

But if I implement Config class shown below:

```java
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers( "/login**" ).permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated();
    }
}
```

The browser returns "404 not found error".
I thought I could be authenticated directly accessing to a Github's API, so implemented this, but it Wouldn't work:

```java
    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String login(){
        return "redirect:/oauth2/authorization/github";
    }
```

How should I cope with that? I know I probably have some misunderstandings because of a lack of my knowledge, 
but I only want to know how to allow access to only a login page when a user is not authenticated.
Thanks.

Comment: If you get a 404, the URL is wrong. Which URL? Either the one you put into the browser adress bar or the redirect URL. Do you have any log messages from the server about your request? Maybe put a simple log message into your `login()` method to check, if your request is actually getting to the endpoint.

Comment: Also, not 100% sure, but I think you are missing an `antMatcher` (singular) statement. `http.antMatcher("/**").authorizeRequests()...`. Don't confuse the `antMatcher` (singular) with the `antMatchers` (plural). They do very different things.

Comment: In my case, I used a default login page generated by DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter and it caused problems. I resolved it by implementing the own login page. It's still unresolved how to use default login page, but at least the error is disappeared. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

finally solved!
I need to append following parts to the end of the methods flow.

```java
    .and()
    .oauth2Login()
    .loginPage("/login");
```

so the final code is:

**`SecurityConfig.java`**

```java
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{
    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/login**")
                .permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                //appended
                .and()
                .oauth2Login()
                .loginPage("/login");
    }
}
```

**`Controller.java`**

```java
    @GetMapping(value = "/login")
    public String getit(Model model){
        return "login";
    }
```

**`login.html`**

```html
<body>
<a th:href="@{/oauth2/authorization/github}">Login</a>
</body>
```

It worked!
Referenced URL:https://www.codeflow.site/ja/article/spring-security-5-oauth2-login